# Overlaying effect for multiple pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got [this](http://jsfiddle.net/L7XCD/764/) code, which works for a single picture.
Nevertheless I wasn't able to figure out, how to adjust the code to make it work, when I'd like to have the same effect for n pictures. Does anybody have any idea, how to generalize this css? Or do I have to use different approach?

```
.cat-image,
.cat-image img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;    
}

.top {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
}

.top .text,
.top button {
    position: absolute;
}

.top .text {
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 30px;
}
.top button {
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 30px;
}

.top:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: You'd need to use some javascript to do this. What is the behavior that you need? Return to the 1st image after the cursor leaves the image? Stay on image for x seconds between transitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `position` of your `.container` to `relative` in your CSS in order to avoid for your multiple images to overlap.

```
.container {
  position:relative;    
}
```

and if you want you images to float one next to the other, all you have to do is add `float:left;`

```
.container {
  position:relative; 
  float:left;
}
```

[Look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7XCD/765/). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you a lot! :) I'm a back end developer and sometimes when I need to make some front end stuff for my private projects, I get pretty stuck on something, that can be very easy to solve in the end tho :D